# "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint" Error for PDF Model Property in Create View

Tags: c#, pdf, model-view-controller, selectlist

I have a model for PDF files that go onto specific webpages depending on what type of documents they are. Instead of handling this myself each time PDFs are uploaded, I assigned a property that I will use in Razor HTML to place the document links on the correct page. That way the client can choose which web page each PDF they upload goes to.

The problem is I am getting an error each time the *Create* view for the PDF files posts:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.PDFBidsLists_dbo.PDFIdentifier_PDFIdentifierID". The conflict occurred in database "FoodService", table "dbo.PDFIdentifier", column 
>   PDFIdentifierID'.

I checked and the `PDFIdentifers` do exist in the database, and they show up in the populated dropdownlist in the Create View

I'm guessing that with the `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` parameter on the `BeginForm` method, I have to explicitly assign the `SelectListItem.SelectedValue` to the `PDFIdentifierID` property of the `PDFBidsList` object, based on how the other properties have to be assigned also (and that the property value is not coming in with the model object passed into the *Create method*). But after a number of searches and different attempts I have not been able to accomplish this.

How do I get a SelectListItem value assigned to a PDF model object's property?

PDFIdentifer Model

```
public class PDFIdentifier
{
    public int PDFIdentifierID { get; set; }

    public string Location { get; set; }        

    public virtual ICollection<PDFBidsLists> PDFBidsLists { get; set; } 
}
```

PDFBidsLists Model

```
public int PDFIdentifierID { get; set; }    

[ForeignKey("PDFIdentifierID")]
public virtual PDFIdentifier PDFIdentifier { get; set; }
```

PDFBidsList Controller Create GET and POST methods

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
...
        ViewBag.PDFsIDList = new SelectList(db.PDFIdentifier, 
        "PDFIdentifierID", "Location"); 
...
    }

 public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PDFBidsListID, PDFTitle, FileName, Content, FileType, PDFIdentifierID")] PDFBidsLists pDFBidsLists, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
    {
        //Check if PDF File input box has a file path entered.
        if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string PDFName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName);
            //Set up the PDF file object.
            var NewPDFFile = new PDFBidsLists { FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName), FileType = FileType.CNLabel };

            //Read the file bytes into the Content property of the CNLabel object.
            using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(upload.InputStream))
            {
                NewPDFFile.Content = reader.ReadBytes(upload.ContentLength);
            }


            NewPDFFile.PDFTitle = pDFBidsLists.PDFTitle;

            db.PDFBidsLists.Add(NewPDFFile);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
        }           

        return View(pDFBidsLists);
    }
```

PDFBidsLists Create View

```
...
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PDFIdentifier.PDFIdentifierID, ( 
IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PDFsIDList, "Select Location", new { 
@class = "form-control" })
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out.

In the Create View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PDFIdentifierID, (SelectList)ViewBag.PDFsIDList, 
"Select Location", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

In the Controller Post Create method:

```
NewPDFFile.PDFIdentifierID = pDFBidsLists.PDFIdentifierID;
```